# Generating Java heap dump in Kubernetes container

Tags: performance, kubernetes, heap-dump, java-heap

I am running a Jenkins Controller in kubernetes. I have noticed that the controller has been restarting ALOT.

```
kgp jkmaster-0
NAME                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jkmaster-0            1/1     Running   8          30m
```

The memory allocation to the pod is as follows

```
    Limits:
      memory:  2500M
    Requests:
      cpu:      300m
      memory:   1G
```

As long as the controller is idle, I dont see any spikes occurring. But as soon as I start spawning jobs, I notice that there are spikes and each spike results in a `OOMError` and a restart happens

[image]

```
kgp jkmaster-0
NAME                  READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
jkmaster-0            0/1     OOMKilled   3          3h8m
```

Inorder to look into this further, I would like to generate a Heap Dump. So what I am done is to add the following

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/srv/jenkins/
```

to `JAVA_OPTS`. I am expecting that the next time when the jenkins controller hits `OOM`, it should generate a Heapdump with under `/srv/jenkins/` but there is none. Any idea if there is something I have missed ?

There is no file of the type `java_pid.hprof` under /srv/jenkins/ after a restart.

All `JAVA_OPTS`

```
JAVA_OPTS: -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=10.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60.0 -server -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+UseStringDeduplication \
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:G1SummarizeRSetStatsPeriod=1 -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true \
-Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.initialDelay=5000 -Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom \
-Xlog:gc:file=/srv/jenkins/gc-%t.log -Xlog:gc*=debug -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+DisableExplicitGC \
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/srv/jenkins/ -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true -Dhudson.model.DownloadService.noSignatureCheck=true
```

Comment: How much ram do your nodes have?

Comment: @paltaa 25GB memory allocatable

Comment: Well, unless you have volume mounted `/srv/jenkins` to a `hostPath:` or a PVC, it is very likely the Pod bounce is resetting the root FS in your container

Comment: @mdaniel `/srv/jenkins` is mounted on a PVC.

Comment: I just now realized the disconnect: OOMKilled is something `kubelet` does _to_ your container, and not something that the JVM does to itself. That process was `kill -9`-ed (in fact, I don't know of any "warning shot" k8s offers the Pod); if you are interested in having the JVM participate in the OOM triage, you'll want to lower the Xmx below the Pod's resource boundary, so the JVM exhausts itself before k8s steps in with a more violent outcome

Comment: @mdaniel great idea. Ill try that